# SlidesJS jumpy sliding

Tags: slidesjs

Both of our sites use the slidesjs library, but you will notice that only on the main site is there a jump at the end of each transition. I have not found any previous topics on this here or on the SlidesJS forum. Any ideas?

Here is our main site:
http://www.xifin.com

And here is our radiology microsite:
http://www.xifin.com/radiology

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK so this has been solved by setting the slides to 100% of their container. The problem was that this was previously set to 50% or so.